# New Computer Weird Glitch with My Minecraft game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I need help to fix or some sort, what should I do please?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a video rendering error.

I would recommend updating your graphics card drivers, and see if other 3D games are functioning properly.

If the updated drivers do not work, I would recommend doing some research specific to your graphics card and see if others are having the same problem with that specific model.

The unfortunate last advice is, your video card may be damaged from use and is not rendering properly.

Comment: It may be a resource pack?